# How do I deal with different keyspace definitions between environments?

Tags: templates, cassandra, environments

i have a code-related question for cassandra.
in dev/qa, we have a 1-node cassandra cluster
in stage/prod environments, we have multiple-nodes in a cluster.
same cluster NAME, same keyspace name, but different replication factors needed.

how does everybody manage their code-base? an example below is when i need to deploy my scripts to dev/qa, we chose a simplestrategy repl factor.
when we need to go to the stage/prod deploy.. we need to now use a NetworkTopologyStrategy with a repl factor = 3.

right now, i'm forced to deploy different scripts, or comment out one line for the other in my scripts:

two versions:

- create_keyspace_tables.dev.cql
- create_keyspace_tables.stg.cql

### sample script contents in which i have to deal with 2 diff replication factors:

```
    -- dev/qa
    -- CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
    -- stage/prod
    -- CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
    USE mykeyspace;
    CREATE TABLE my_table (
        storeNumber text,
        businessDate timestamp,
```

Comment: update to this: I'm now learning that cassandra / datastax enterprise actually allows me to create a keysapce with NetworkTopologyStrategy, even with a single node. that way, i can keep my keyspace code the SAME instead of having to fork the 'create code' in this manner.

can anybody confirm this behaviour at all?